# Robot framework-how to replace 'list files in a directory' keyword by an .csv file containing the list of files

Tags: frameworks, robotframework

I have a .csv files which contain all the files in the directory.

```
CSV
1,txt1.txt
2,txt2.txt
3,txt3.txt
4,txtsum.txt
```

These four text files and csv file  are there in my directory c:/data i want to fetch the names of the files from the csv file insted of using the keyword 'list files in a directory'.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing what you want? What sort of help do you need? Have you tried using any of the already-available csv libraries?

Comment: here is what you need https://github.com/s4int/robotframework-CSVLibrary